# How to not use apache port from site URL with acquia drupal

Tags: drupal, acquia

Acquia drupal always puts the apache port :8082 to the end of site url, e.g.: http://localhost:8082.

I have a custom site url:
http://somesite:8082

I want to access it just by http://somesite

How to make it work without :8082?

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See if http://serverfault.com/questions/80368/how-do-i-remove-the-port-number-from-tomcat-urls helps

Comment: Thanks, I still need default 80 for another application. But there seems to be another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you're kind of out of luck.  The only way to get that port to go away is to server on either port 80 (http) or 443 (https).  Web browsers treat those as the default ports, hence, you don't have to specify.  You *need* the port there so that the browser knows where to go to find Drupal.  If you can't run the Acquia Drupal Apache server on port 80, you could optionally run a proxy on port 80 that redirects to the correct place.  However that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Basically, don't worry about it, whenever you move your site off of your localhost onto a live server, you'll be able to run in on port 80 and that pesky port number won't be there anymore.